# Cant save data into Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is all the code with register account with email password, save verify email, save user data into Firestore database. Only the Firestore database can't run.

```
fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful()){

            // send verification link

            FirebaseUser fuser = fAuth.getCurrentUser();
            fuser.sendEmailVerification().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Toast.makeText(register.this, "Verification Email Has been Sent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: Email not sent " + e.getMessage());
                }
            });

            Toast.makeText(register.this, "User Created.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            userID = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(userID);
            Map<String,Object> user = new HashMap<>();
            user.put("fName",fullName);
            user.put("email",email);
            user.put("phone",phone);
            documentReference.set(user).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: user Profile is created for "+ userID);
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "onFailure: " + e.toString());
                }
            });
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));

        }
```

else {
Toast.makeText(register.this, "Error ! " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
}
});
}
});

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code as text and **not** as an image.

Comment: Edited, the authentication in firebase is workable, but I want to store user data into firestore it does not works.

Comment: Even I add log but in logcat is does not show anythings

Comment: rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}

Comment: this is my firestore rules

Comment: Is your onSuccess or onFailure even triggered?

Comment: I think no, because logcat does not show any message for it.

Comment: But I really no idea for now, it does not show any error.

Comment: When I register, only the Toast message "user created" shown and it return out to login page but normally it will go to the mainactivity page

Comment: So you say that the user is successfully created, right? In that case, it makes sense. Show us that code.

Comment: the user have created with email and password in firebase authentication, but the user data not store in the firestore database.

Comment: I have post all the code, the firestore code is together with the user created code.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Ok, I'll write you an answer right away.

Comment: Sir, I have solved the problem, the problem is not on the code, is on the android simulator version, when I'm using android 11.0 with api level 30 is not workable, but i change to android 7.1.1 with api level 25 it work for me.

Answer (score 4):

The Firebase authentication operation is asynchronous. This means that you can be sure that authentication succeeded only when the `onSuccess()` method fires. Since you say that the authentication process successfully completes, your first `onSuccess()` is triggered. Your second `onSuccess()` is not triggered because the code that corresponds to the addition of data to Firestore is outside the callback, hence that behavior. To solve this, all the code that exists outside the callback should be **moved** inside the first `onSuccess()` as explained in the following line of code:

```
fAuth
.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful()){

            // send verification link

            FirebaseUser fuser = fAuth.getCurrentUser();
            fuser.sendEmailVerification().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Toast.makeText(register.this, "Verification Email Has been Sent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Toast.makeText(register.this, "User Created.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //Moved code 
                    userID = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(userID);
                    Map<String,Object> user = new HashMap<>();
                    user.put("fName",fullName);
                    user.put("email",email);
                    user.put("phone",phone);
                    documentReference.set(user).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: user Profile is created for "+ userID);
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "onFailure: " + e.toString());
                        }
                    });
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));

                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: Email not sent " + e.getMessage());
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(register.this, "Error ! " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
});
```

In this way, you be able to write the data to Firestore when the authentication process is completed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238209/discussion-on-answer-by-alex-mamo-document-referent-cant-write-into-firestore).